# gmail redirects to original country even after updating it

Tags: email, gmail, redirection

When I signed up to Gmail I was in Algeria so I chose Algeria as the country, but now am not anymore there.

I changed the setting on my profile but whenever I signing to my Gmail I takes like 15 seconds redirecting to the google.dz domain which is almost all the time down, so I have to enter the .com domain again.

Anyone has an Idea how to correct this? Thank you

Comment: How long ago did you change the setting on your profile? Maybe it takes some time to update the redirect behavior?

Comment: I remember myself changing it for over year now.

Comment: wow... ok, then that's not it :) So it's over a year that you have this problem? 15 seconds? WTF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible .. gmail account is specific to a country based on where it has been created and that you can change it all you want it will stay in the country where it has been created. You should create a new account and redirect all the mail from your current account to the new one

Comment: Someone, please make this real English. I can't understand what he's trying to say!

Comment: I think he's trying to say that a gmail account is specific to a country based on where it has been created and that you can change it all you want it will stay in the country where it has been created. You should create a new account and redirect all the mail from your current account to the new one.

Comment: hahaaa, you think that's a solution?

Comment: @martani_net, it might be best not to taunt those that provide answers for you.  If you really think the answer doesn't work, there are other ways to show your dissatisfaction.

Comment: sorry, just wanted to say that creating a new account is not an option

Answer (score 3):

If it's really already a year you're having this problem and a Google search doesn't return meaningful hits, I would suggest posting your problem on the [Gmail Help Forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail?hl=en). I guess you'll have more luck there as Google Engineers will monitor that forum.

I've found [this issue](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hlrm=en-uk&answer=873) (about ip-adresses) which is similar but more related to Search than to Mail that maybe can help. If it's really your ip-address that's the showstopper here (although I doubt that as you're experiencing this already for a year), you can [report it here](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/request.py?contact_type=ip).

Comment: already posted one 7 days before here http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=6b59f6fa981b2875&hl=en still didn't get any answer

Comment: wow strange I didn't encounter that one over there... I did search for 'redirect country'... is that google behind that forum for sure??? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your browser cookies - google may have left a preferences cookie on your machine to redirect you to the local version.

Comment: no that happen from whatever pc I user, at work or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but are you changing your google account information rather than gmail settings? Did you try changing it at [My Account](https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageAccount)?

Comment: yep I did and the country is france in there, but it redirects to .dz domain

Answer (score 1):

Tip found [here](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=873):

Bookmark http://www.google.com/webhp. This is an alternative web address for Google.com that always takes you to Google.com without redirecting you.

Comment: This too http://www.google.com/ncr redirect always to the .com domain, but this work for Google and not Gmail unfortunately

Comment: How about mail.google.com/ncr ?

Comment: The problem is not actually in the Gmail login page, when I'm on gmail.com I enter my user and pass, then when authenticating it go to google.dz and once authenticated it turn again to mail.google.com! Most of the time google.dz is down, so when it redirects there it fails, so I refresh the page with google.com and it work normally! So just the authentication on the DZ domain is the problem